# How are separated sampled images and samplers used in Vulkan with GLSL?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I just finished writing up the code for my texture and sampler objects, but now I am stumped on how to implement the separated descriptors into GLSL.

Accessing a combined image sampler in descriptor set 0, binding 0 would be done using:

```
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D texSampler;
```

The fragment shader would then sample the image using `sampler2D` and the `texture` function:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec2 fragTexCoord;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    outColor = texture(texSampler, fragTexCoord);
}
```

From what I understand, a descriptor set (or binding) is created for a sampler using `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLER` and another is created for a sampled image with the type `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLED_IMAGE`. However, I do not know what syntax would be used to access the separate descriptors.

```
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform /* idk what type it is */ sampler
layout(set = 0, binding = 1) uniform /* idk */ sampledImage
// alternatively...
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform /* idk */ sampler
layout(set = 1, binding = 0) uniform /* idk */ sampledImage
```

Are samplers and images stored in different sets/bindings as specified when creating the descriptor sets?

If `sampler2D` is used for combined image samplers with the descriptor type `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER`, then what is the syntax used for each of the separated types?

`VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLER`, `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLED_IMAGE`, `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_IMAGE`, `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_TEXEL_BUFFER`, and `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_TEXEL_BUFFER`?

How would these separated objects be called in `main` to set the `outColor` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GLSL types `sampler*` (where `*` is the type of a texture, such a `1D`, `Cube`, etc) represent descriptors of the form `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER`.

As specified in the [GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl extension](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/khr/GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl.txt), the GLSL type `sampler` (no `*`) represents a descriptor of the form `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLER`. For descriptors of the form `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLED_IMAGE`, the appropriate GLSL types are `texture*` (where `*` is again the type of the texture).

To combine a sampled image with a sampler, you create a `sampler*` object from the two using constructor syntax: `texture(sampler2D(t, s), ...);`